# APP crashing on android devices, game built with unity editor 2020.3.33 LTS

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging, crash

I am working on a project from last 2 years. I started working with 2019.4. Few months ago my PC broke down because of heat so i had to take a new one. I installed unity 2.4.5hub and 2020.3.28(later 2020.3.33) LTS releases to continue the project. I have API 30 SDK and supported gradle as well as JDK and NDK.

The app build were success with editor 2019.4 and APP were working fine with any devices.
The issue is now when i am trying to run on any android device it crashes just on unity splash screen. I got some log cat from google Console mentioned bellow:

Stack trace

Native crash of com.XYZ.AMGame

FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
Process: com.XYZ.AMGame, PID: 19127
java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.33f1 (915a7af8b0d5)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'DOCOMO/SH-01L/SH-01L:9/S1240/02.00.05:user/release-keys'

Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-04-19 02:33:55-0700
pid: 19127, tid: 19560, name: UnityMain  >>> com.XYZ.AMGame<<<
uid: 10274
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7e31804ff0
x0  0000007e1fcf4ee8  x1  0000007e1cc20e20  x2  0000007e1cc20e20  x3  0000007e3180509c
x4  0000007e1cc21100  x5  0000000000000004  x6  0000007e31808f59  x7  0800000000000000
x8  0000000000000a79  x9  6db6db6db6db6db7  x10 0000000000000038  x11 0000007e1d75b498
x12 0000000000002373  x13 0000000000000537  x14 0000000000000300  x15 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
x16 0000007ed06af270  x17 0000007ed05be430  x18 0000000000000001  x19 0000007e1fd8b850
x20 0000007e31805088  x21 0000007e3180509d  x22 0000000000000038  x23 ffffffffffffffff
x24 000000000000017f  x25 00000000000000bf  x26 0000007e1fd8e218  x27 0000007e1d75b498
x28 0000007e1fdae000  x29 0000007e31805020
sp  0000007e31805020  lr  0000007e1ea289a8  pc  0000007e1ea28818
backtrace:
#00 pc 0000000000562818  /data/app/com.XYZ.AMGame-gymaxWfE3AwNPqfOQwDg1Q==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 95f042fcd17ee217a64223a559ce49e73fae8e1a)

at libil2cpp.0x562818(Native Method)
at libil2cpp.0x5629a4(Native Method)
at libil2cpp.0x543790(Native Method)
at libil2cpp.0x515a78(Native Method)
at libil2cpp.0x516ac0(Native Method)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've started getting (what looks like) this same crash since updating from Unity 2020.3.26 to 2020.3.33.
Building for ARM64 (excluding ARMv7) fixes it, but I need ARMv7 support in my shipped game.
This in an APK build for testing; building to an AAB might also fix it, but that's going to be harder to test.

Comment: Update: Changing the Target API to Level 31 also fixes it. (requires installing new SDK).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).